# updating query in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my controller submenu.php

```
 public function update_submenu() {



       $id = $_POST['id'];
       $name = $_POST['name'];
       $url = $_POST['url'];
       $cat=$_POST['category'];
       $result=$this->submenu_model->update_subcategory($id,$name,$url,$cat);

       $arr['page'] = 'submenu';
       $this->load->view('admin/vwEditSubmenu',$arr);

}

 public function edit_submenu($id='') {
    $arr['page'] = 'submenu';
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    if($id!='')
    {
    $result=$this->submenu_model->get_id();
    $this->load->view('admin/vwEditSubmenu',$arr);
    }
```

this my model submenu_model.php

```
 function update_subcategory($id,$name,$url,$cat)
    {
             $data = array(
           'namesubcategory' => $name,
           'urlsubcategory' => $url,
           'idcategory' => $cat
        );

        $this->db->where('idsubcategory', $id);
         $this->db->update('subcategory', $data); 
         }
             function get_id()
                {
              $query = $this->db->get_where('subcategory', array('id' => 
              $id), $limit, $offset);
              return $query->result();
               }
```

this is view vwEditSubmenu.php

```
          <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ? 
          >admin/submenu/edit_submenu">
          <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php  
                echo isset($submenu[0]['namesubcategory']) &&  
         !empty($submenu[0]['namesubcategory']) ? $submenu[0]
         ['namesubcategory'] : '';     
                ?>">
         <input type="text" name="url" value="<?php  
                echo isset($submenu[0]['urlsubcategory']) &&

          !empty($submenu[0]['urlsubcategory']) ? $submenu[0]
           ['urlsubcategory'] :   
            '';     
                ?>" >
          <select name="category">
          <?php
          $q=mysql_query('select * from category');
          $cnt=mysql_num_rows($q);
          if($cnt>0)
         {
         while($d=mysql_fetch_array($q))
        enter code here{

          ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $d['idcategory']; ?>">
         <?php echo $d['namecategory']; ?></option>
          <?php } }?>
         </select>
           <input type="submit" name="submit" >

             `enter code here`</form>
```

Now the error isSeverity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: id

Filename: admin/submenu.php

Line Number: 63

How to solve the error please suggest me in code...thanx

Comment: No filed name `id` in your form!!!

Comment: Can you show us your form??

Comment: no actually there is a name, url and a dropdown of parent menu name and a update button..

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an "id" in url.

You can add `<input type='hidden' name='id' value='_submenu_id_'>`

in your form and set the value when you load the view like :

`$datas = array('id' => $id);
$this->load->view('your/view/', $datas);`

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting an id to be posted or in the url, so you should add a field to your form with the name 'id', or add the id to the form action, this way the id parameter of the `edit_submenu` will contain your id.

Pass the id to the view:

```
$data = array();
$data['id'] = $id
$this->load->view('viewname',$data);
```

Then retrieve the id like so:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/submenu/edit_submenu/<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

By doing this you won't have to add a field to your form with the id.